# SeekBar inside DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-scroll

I have a SeekBar inside the end panel of a DrawerLayout

The problem is that we can't swipe the Seekbar without closing the Right Panel.

If tryed to play by overriding the methods onTouchEvent and closeDrawer of DrawerLayout without success

Comment: Post up your code please

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found it :)

```
mSeekBar.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            mProgressBar.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            return false;
        }
    });
```